# How to use the android library after assemble

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-library

I know how to write Android library. And after writing I'm `assemble` it to build `aar` files. But how t use it in my project. I have `FirstLibrary` folder in my project itself but I'm not getting how to use it. Android didn't gave any documentation anywhere on internet.

You can have a look at the library I created below `FirstLibrary` inside my project.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add this in app level build.gradle

```
implementation project(':app:FirstLibrary')
```

Library name can be found in `settings.gradle`

if you have created everything manually then you must have include the library name in `settings.gradle`. If you have created android library by panel itself then it would be added automatically.